# Visual Studio always restoring because Directry.Build.props

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, assemblyinfo

I created a `Directory.Build.props` file, with `VersionSuffix` contain the current `Hour` and `Minutes`:

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionSuffix>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm))-$(Configuration)</VersionSuffix>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now, because this file changed every minute, the *Visual Studio* complete it auto-restore, and start it again, because after a minute the properties are different.

So, I added a `Target` to update the properties only before the `Build`:

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Version" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <VersionSuffix>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm))-$(Configuration)</VersionSuffix>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Now the *Visual Studio* works fine, but from the command-line (`msbuild MySln.sln /t:Build...`) the properties don't apply.

(I tried with `Directory.Build.targets` and it acts the same (unless I missed something))

(You can try with more simple property, `Company` for example).

**How can I use a time-based property, but apply it only when I creating the DLL?**

Comment: You know, I have to wait a few days until I can mark an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `InitialTargets` solved my problem:

```xml
<Project InitialTargets="Version" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Version">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <VersionSuffix>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm))-$(Configuration)</VersionSuffix>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```